# CircleCI: ESLint returns exit code 0 on CI altough tests are failing

Tags: continuous-integration, eslint, yarnpkg, circleci

I'm executing the following command in my CircleCI pipeline:

```
yarn run eslint . --ext .json --ext .js --format junit -o reports/junit/eslint/js-lint-results.xml
```

[image: Output when executing the linting command]

The output shows exit code 0, altough there are multiple linting errors. Even the test summary from CircleCI shows those failures.
[image: Test Summary in CircleCI]

When executing the same command locally (on Windows and Unix), it fails with exit code 1 (which should also be the case on CircleCI).

Comment: Which `eslint` version are you using?

Comment: I'm using eslint version 4.19.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using an older version on Yarn locally? In recent versions of Yarn, `yarn run` no longer bubbles up the exit code. This is probably why this is occuring. If you see the errors in `yarn-error.log` then this is what's happening.

There's an open Issue for Yarn on this: https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/5457